# How to assign passFunction to wizardPane programmatically?

Tags: dojo, wizard

I know the way to assign passFunction to WizardPane through declarative method.
Through below we can assign passFunction :

```
<div dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" id="myId" passFunction='ValidateInfo'>
```

I want to create same functionality but through programmatically. I am creating widget using below code
 `var wizard = new wizard({style: "width:100%;height:400px"}, "myDataSetWindow");
wizard.addChild(new WizardPane({label: 'Create', id:  'myId',  content: "Content 1"})); 
wizard.startup();`

I want to add function 'ValidateInfo' through property 'passFunction'. Can you please let me the way how I can do?

Comment: Js fiddle link jsfiddle.net/XHS9k

Answer (score 0):

Try `wizard.set("passFunction", ValidateInfo)` before `startup()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually passFunction is a property of 'WizardPane' not of the 'Wizard' so it is not working. I tried your code.

Comment: so, try to assign wizardPane to some var and use my "set" function?:)

Comment: Yes tried that one also, but not working . :( like below           var child = new WizardPane({label: 'Create', id:  'myId', passFunction: 'test', content: "Content 1"});
   child.set('passFunction', testNew);
   wizard.addChild(child);

Comment: Do u have any errors during validation? try to use inline validate function, it could be scope problem...

Comment: No, I have just added console log in that function.

Comment: create demo @ jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: Created. But don't know why it is not working over there http://jsfiddle.net/XHS9k/

Comment: Fix ur fiddle to just show one problem at the time... (add dojo lib, and create some demo button where u would like to use validate function).